# Apple Mach-O Linker Error For All My Apps

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to figure out why I keep receiving this error when running my apps in Xcode. It randomly started showing up and I was wondering if someone could help me resolve.

Here is what it tells me in the logs:

```
ld: file not found: /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CrossWay-cayoqfvpvetpcpdpwgowzevnomkx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GP.app/GP
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why is it trying to find the file "GP.app/GP" instead of just "GP.app"?

Edit: Here is my build settings screenshot
[image]

Edit: Here is the log screenshot
[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you attach a screenshot of your `BuildSettings->OtherLinkerFlags` ?

Comment: Sure! Attached just now.

Comment: Hm..need to more informations. Can you post the full build log? (On the top of ProjectArea the right icon)

Comment: Gotcha, I edited the post and added the log

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error has been caused by compiling a Tests target. Try to disable running tests at scheme's settings (Product -> Scheme -> Manage Schemes -> your scheme -> edit -> Build -> remove all marks for all rows under the Test column)

Answer (score 0):

In your attached linker log is found the next string

```
-bundle_loader /Users/User/..bla-bla/GP.app/GP
```

Open `BuildSettings->Linking` and clean a settings for `Bundle Loader`.